# write a text file with the results of a query in vbs

Tags: vbscript

I am fairly new to Visual Basic scripting and have ran into a problem. I am using Notepad++ and right now when I go into the Command Prompt, I can get my query to run successfully, and the results are returned in a msgbox. Instead of making the result of the query pop up in a message box, I want the results to be saved into a text file.

The result of this query is just a count, looking for errors, so it would be nice if I could put the word errors after the result. ("23 errors")

Also whenever I run the script, I need the text file to be replaced with the newest version of the text file (Kind of like an X copy.)

```
    Dim connStr, objConn, getNumber
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Define the driver and data source
    'Access 2007, 2010, 2013 ACCDB:
    'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
    'Access 2000, 2002-2003 MDB:
    'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=Q:\Temp 8 Days Only\SAPDTW\eric_copy_dtw.mdb"

    'Define object type
    Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    'Open Connection
    objConn.Open connStr

    'Define recordset and SQL query
    Set rs = objConn.Execute("select count(*) from OLOG where (AddFaiCnt + UpdFaiCnt) > 0 and DateValue(DateTime)>=Date()-1")

    'While loop, loops through all available results
    Do While Not rs.EOF
    'add names seperated by comma to getNames
    getNumber = getNumber + rs.Fields(0) & "," 
    'move to next result before looping again
    'this is important
    rs.MoveNext
    'continue loop
    Loop

    'Close connection and release objects
    objConn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set objConn = Nothing


    Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    outFile="c:\test\autorun.inf"
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
    objFile.Write "test string" & vbCrLf
    objFile.Close
   'Return Results via MsgBox
```

this is what I have now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying the FSO Calls and Write(s) emit to a MsgBox instead of creating and writing to file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.. Replace your execute statement with either of the following:

If you like the parentheses try...

```
'Define recordset and SQL query
Set rs = objConn.Execute("select '(' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' errors)' from OLOG where (AddFaiCnt + UpdFaiCnt) > 0 and DateValue(DateTime)>=Date()-1")
```

If you don't care for parentheses try...

```
'Define recordset and SQL query
Set rs = objConn.Execute("select CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' errors' from OLOG where (AddFaiCnt + UpdFaiCnt) > 0 and DateValue(DateTime)>=Date()-1")
```

If CAST() isnt recognized as a function in access sql try...

```
'Define recordset and SQL query
Set rs = objConn.Execute("select Str(COUNT(*)) + ' errors' from OLOG where (AddFaiCnt + UpdFaiCnt) > 0 and DateValue(DateTime)>=Date()-1")
```

Know that in order to concatenate string data to something that is an integer datatype, the integer datatype must be casted/converted to a datatype which you can append a string to it , hence varchar. Hope that helps.

Good luck..